# Upper body workout following a groin pull

Tags: recovery, injury, rehabilitation

What kind of upper body weight lifting and strengthening exercises can I resume if I pulled my groin 1 1/2 weeks ago? I think it is about a grade 1 groin pull, maybe 1.5

Comment: If it were me, I'd take some time off and work on rehabbing the pull.  That type of injury can be tough to overcome.

Comment: @JohnP John, where are you? I can't believe you have not yet voted to close this question! It is a medical issue. The OP has self-diagnosed himself and is asking for delicate advise on how to injure himself further by exercising with a recently pulled groin!

Answer (score 1):

I yanked an [adductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adductor_muscles_of_the_hip) the other day. Just speaking from my own experience, it played out a little like this:

- Deadlifting was okay.
- [Overhead pressing](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/DeltoidAnterior/BBMilitaryPress.html), [bench pressing](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/PectoralSternal/BBBenchPress.html), [pullups](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/LatissimusDorsi/BWPullup.html), and [dips](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Triceps/BWTriDip.html) were all fine.
- Squatting I waited about a week, then started with ramping sets (empty bar, 50% of [1RM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-repetition_maximum), 60% of 1RM, I think I maxed around 75% of 1RM.
- Olympic lifts I waited on until my squat was back to normal.
- I was healed up fully in about two weeks.

In general I'd just say that anything where you need a wide stance is going to be problematic and aggravating. Where your knees are relatively close together and you're not engaging your hip adductors as much, you should be okay.